# Pytest Generate Tests Based on Arguments

Tags: python, pytest

New to pytest...

I have the following in conftest.py to collect a team argument from the command line, and read in a yaml config file:

```
import pytest
import yaml


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        '--team',
        action='store',
        )


@pytest.fixture
def team(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--team')


@pytest.fixture
def conf(request):
    with open('config.yml', 'r') as f:
        conf = yaml.load(f.read())
    return conf
```

I want to run a test on each player inside conf[team]['players'] (a list). I can do so as follows in test_players.py:

```
def test_players(team, conf):
    players = conf[team]['players']
    for p in players:
        assert p == something
```

This sort of works, in that it iterates through the players, but the whole thing gets treated as a single test. If anything fails the whole test is treated as failed. I'd like each player to be tested separately.

If I put in the players manually I can get this to work:

```
import pytest

class Test_Player():
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'player', [
            'player1',
            'player2',
            'player3',
        ],
    )
    def test_player(self, player):
        assert player == something
```

So my problem is that I don't know how to get conf[team] passed into pytest.mark.parametrize. I've tried these, but in both cases it complains that conf isn't defined.

```
import pytest

class Test_Player():
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'player', conf[team]['players'],
    )
    def test_player(self, player):
        assert player == something
```

and

```
import pytest

class Test_Player(team, conf):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'player', conf[team]['players'],
    )
    def test_player(self, player):
        assert player == something
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem with your setup is that you want to parameterize on `conf[team]`, but `conf` needs to be defined at *import* time, because that's when the decorator executes.

So, you'll have to go about this parameterization differently, using pytest's [metafunc parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#_pytest.python.Metafunc.parametrize) features.

```
.
├── conftest.py
├── teams.yml
└── test_bobs.py
```

In the yaml file:

```
# teams.yml
bobs: [bob1, bob2, potato]
pauls: [paultato]
```

In the test module:

```
# test_bobs.py
def test_player(player):
    assert 'bob' in player
```

In the pytest conf:

```
import pytest
import yaml


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--team', action='store')


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'player' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        team_name = metafunc.config.getoption('team')

        # you can move this part out to module scope if you want
        with open('./teams.yml') as f:
            teams = yaml.load(f)

        metafunc.parametrize("player", teams.get(team_name, []))
```

Now execute:

```
pytest --team bobs
```

You should see three tests executed: two passing tests (bob1, bob2) and one failing test (potato).  Using `pytest --team pauls` will make  one failing test.  Using `pytest --team bogus` will result in a skipped test.  If you want a different behaviour there, change the `teams.get(team_name, [])` to, for example, `teams[team_name]`.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. The only issue I'm having with it is that I have additional tests don't require the player "metafunc.parametrize". Now any other tests I try to run gives ValueError: <function test_somethingelse at 0x7f957d9221e0> uses no argument 'player'

Comment: Basically what I'm hoping to do is mix generated tests alongside other regular tests.

Comment: Did you include the `if 'player' in metafunc.fixturenames:` part?   If I add another test in `test_bobs.py` without using the `player` fixture, it still works fine.  Create an MCVE, please.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it. I took out that if statement when I was "improving" the code you provided. Thanks a lot, everything is working exactly as I want now.