# Using a fixture inside pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, pytest

Say I have a test function that takes a parametrize `record` as a dict, where one of its values is a fixture which is already defined.

For example, we have a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def a_value():
    return "some_value"
```

And the test function:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("record", [{"a": a_value, "other": "other_value"},
                                    {"a": a_value, "another": "another_value"}])
def test_record(record):
    do_something(record)
```

Now, I know that this can be solved by passing the fixture to the test function and updating the record accordingly, like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("record", [{"other": "other_value"},
                                    {"another": "another_value"}])
def test_record(a_value, record):
    record["a"] = a_value
    do_something(record)
```

But I was wondering if there is a way of doing this without this "workaround", when I have many fixtures that are already defined and I just want to use them in each parametrized record I pass to the function.

I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42014484/3132173), although it doesn't seem to fit my case exactly. Couldn't find a correct use from the answers there.

Comment: Related:  [metafunc parametrization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117044/674039)

Comment: Thanks @wim - If I understand correctly, this requires me to modify the comment for running the tests. Is there a way to do it by code?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create `record` as a fixture rather than using `parametrize` and accept `a_value` as a paraemter:

```
@pytest.fixture
def record(a_value):
    return {
        'a': a_value,
        'other': 'other_value',
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But then, how do you parametrize over different `record`s? I've edited my question to have few different values for the `record` parameter.

Comment: @A.Sarid In your example, the record only has two fields. In practice, how many fields will the records really have?

Comment: Varies, that's the whole reason for using the parametrize, some will have 2 and some will have more key-value pairs. Although all records will include a fixture such as `a_value` in my example.

Comment: @A.Sarid I tip from someone who knows more than I do about pytest suggested `metafunc.parametrize`: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example