# How to group redundant values in pytest parametrize test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to remove redundant rows in my parametrized tests. Redundant - I mean I repeat this kind of code all the time.

Here is example of my test:

```
1  @pytest.mark.parametrize("field, violations", [
2      (None, [NULL_VIOLATION]),
3      (True, []),
4      (False, [])
5  ])
6  def test_validate_field(field: str, violations: [str]):
7      ...
```

As you can see, lines: 2,3,4 are simple test of annotation @NotNull in my Controller Class.
Line 2 is **bad path** test and line 3,4 are **happy path**.

---

I repeat those 3 lines in every test when I need to check @NotNull
**Is it possible to inline this somehow?**

---

What I want to achieve is something similar to that pseudo code:

```
1  @pytest.mark.parametrize("field, violations", [
2      check_not_null_constraint()
3  ])
4  def test_validate_field(field: str, violations: [str]):
5      ...
```

---

I don't want to get rid of parametrized because instead of checking that not_null I am testing many other things like size etc. I am testing everything per parameter. So 1 test for 1 parameter in class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the following: put the list of the paths into a variable, which contains a list...

```
path_params = [(None, [NULL_VIOLATION]), (True, []), (False, [])]
```

And then, pass that variable into `parametrize`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("field, violations", path_params)
```

UPD: naturally, this would only work if you want to reuse these exact params in other tests; for similar stuff, the other answer would probably work better...

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using `pytest_generate_tests` See: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html

This test setup:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "a, b",[(1,10),(2,20)]
)
def test_param_func1(a, b):
    assert 10*a == b

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "a, b",[(1,10),(2,20)]
)
def test_param_func2(a, b):
    assert a in (1,2)  
    assert b in (10,20)
```

```
$ pytest -v -k "test_param"
test_param.py::test_param_func1[1-10] PASSED [ 25%] 
test_param.py::test_param_func1[2-20] PASSED [ 50%] 
test_param.py::test_param_func2[1-10] PASSED [ 75%] 
test_param.py::test_param_func2[2-20] PASSED [100%]
```

Can also be achieved like this:

```
import pytest

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # This hook function runs once per test function
    metafunc.parametrize("a, b",[(1,10),(2,20)])

def test_param_func3(a, b):
    assert 10*a == b

def test_param_func4(a, b):
    assert a in (1,2)  
    assert b in (10,20)
```

```
$ pytest -v -k "test_param"
test_param.py::test_param_func3[1-10] PASSED [ 25%] 
test_param.py::test_param_func3[2-20] PASSED [ 50%] 
test_param.py::test_param_func4[1-10] PASSED [ 75%] 
test_param.py::test_param_func5[2-20] PASSED [100%]
```

You can take it a step farther and parametrize your tests conditionally based on command-line arguments using `metafunc.config.getoption("--yourflag")` ([Pytest Generate Tests Based on Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076378/pytest-generate-tests-based-on-arguments#49117044))